# Git merge with commit overwrite

Tags: git

I created a branch A from master. On this branch I executed `rebase --i` and renamed a few commits, that were present from the beginning. Now I would like to merge branch A back to master, overwriting the commits from master with their messages set on branch A. However if I call `merge` The commits from branch A are put on top of commits already on `master`. Is there a way to force replacing the old commits from `master` with their updated version on branch A?

Comment: What about reverting the commits in master?

Comment: Why not just delete master and rename your branch `master`?

Comment: You mean reverting all the commits from the beginning and then merging? Might be an idea, but I'm hoping there is a better way

Comment: Just to understand this correctly: you want to get rid of everything currently in master and make `A` the new `master`? (disclaimer: history must not be published for this, otherwise you will cause quite some headache down the road)

Comment: @Paolo wouldn't that mess up any other history? Also considering I have a few other branches following Git Flow then it seems like a lot of work, vulnerable to human error (edit: I mean that each of these branches should be rebased manually if I understand it correctly)

Comment: @knittl yes, my `master` should have exactly the same history as branch `A` at the moment

Comment: Has there been made additional work on master while you were working on your A branch, additional work that you want to keep?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, there isn't

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** Do not change already-published Git history without understanding the consequences. It can cause problems for others and for you. Read up on all warnings about force-pushing or rebasing.

If I understood you correctly and you have confirmed this in a comment, what you have at the moment is:

```
a-b-c--d--e <- master
   \
    c'-d'-e' <- A
```

And you want that to be come:

```
a-b (-c--d--e)
   \
    c'-d'-e' <- A, master
```

Then, you can simply delete the master branch and recreate at at the appropriate commit. Or, force-create it (the result is the same):

```
git branch -f master A
```

This will create a branch `master` which points to the same commit as `A`, including all of A's history. Existing history of the *old `master`* will be lost.

Comment: There is a slight missunderstanding. `A` was created from the newest master (in this case `a-b-c-d-e <- A` and using interactive rebase I have renamed the commit messages to eg. `a-b'-c-d'-e <- A`. I will edit the question to better explain that

Comment: @Elgirhath yes, this is exactly what I have posted in my answer. `A` contains a set of commits which are similar to those on master. There will be shared commits (those that were unchanged). But even if there were not, the procedure would be the same

Comment: @Elgirhath Git is a beautifully distributed tool. Create a copy of your local clone, and try the commands in your copy. If they don't work as expected, deleted the copy and try again. If they worked, create a backup (just in case ;)) and perform them in your real clone.

Comment: You're right. The only problem seems to be that any branch which had a root on master will need to be rebased on the new master

Comment: @Elgirhath yes, that's correct. Since a branch is only a label and "history" is defined by parent-pointers of the commits, a rebase or reset will only move that label and not change any other commits (which could effectively destroy unrelated history). Labeling has the benefit of being able to easily create "backups" of history. Add a label/branch and you cannot lose the commits.